# Vanishing of motivic cohomology with finite coefficients in negative degrees

Tags: chow-groups, motivic-cohomology, arithmetic-geometry, finite-fields

I wonder whether the "finite coefficient version" of Beilinson-Soule conjecture i.e. the following statement holds or not.

STATEMENT:

Let $X$ be a smooth and projective scheme over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.

Then, Bloch's higher chow group $CH_{0}(X,i,\mathbb{Z}/n)$ vanishes for $n$ satisfying (n,p) =1 and $i>2dim(X)$.

Please give me any advice.

Comment: $n\in\mathbf{F}_q^\times$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant n is an integer prime to p.

Comment: Why don't you just say that $(p,n) = 1$, or (perhaps more usefully) that $p$ is invertible in the coefficient ring $\mathbb{Z}/n$?

Comment: This is probably true; it should be an easy consequence of the Beilinson-Lichtenbaum conjecture (that was recently proved by Voevodsky and others). 

Comment: See this paper
http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/handbook/1-351-428.pdf
(in particular, page 379 in it).

Comment: For other fields and cohomological Chow groups, a Beilinson-Soulé vanishing can be found in R.Akhtar: A mod $\ell$ vanishing theorem of Beilinson-Soulé type. JPAA 208 (2007), 555-560.